# Fuse sensors with different accuracy in robot_localization

Tags: navigation, ekf, sensor, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the better way to fuse sensors with different accuracy in robot_localization that measure the same values of state vector? initial_estimate_covariance is set for state vector, not for sensors. How set noise for each sensors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242059/fuse-sensors-with-different-accuracy-in-robot_localization/) by [vladimir](https://answers.ros.org/users/27791/vladimir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

r_l will read sensors' measuring convariance in msg you feed and estimate.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1